# Cucumber-jvm testing rows in parallel

Tags: selenium, parallel-processing, cucumber-jvm

It appears the granularity of parallelism in running cucumber-jvm tests is at the scenario level? If the scenario is truly independent then running the rows within the scenario independently would also be of benefit where a test suite has access to a considerable selenium grid bank?

Out of the box is it possible to run the test rows in parallel? Would there be any reason this may not be a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is completely possible to run cucumberJVM scenarios independently in parallel, using this plugin: https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin.

it will generate runners for you at either A) feature level or B) scenario level using forked processes.  You should then in theory be able to pass those scenario runs to a sizeable selenium grid setup with many nodes.

Comment: Thanks Simon. It appears the granularity of test is at the scenario level? Perhaps my understanding of cucumber is a little lacking. We have developed a number of features with one scenario in each and a number of Page Input rows at the bottom that correspond to one flow through that particular branch of the system . I'm looking to find out if there's a way to run the rows in parallel.